# Is the differential equation $y''(x)+x^2\cos y(x)=0$ linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a ordinary equation as" 2 times derivative of y w.r.t. x +square of x multiplied by cos y=0"
Question is to tell whether it is linear or non linear.??

According to me since double derivative has degree 1 and also function of y has degree 1and no product of dependent function and any derivative seen .so it must be linear  . But my text book says it is non linear .
Plzzz correct me if i m wrong.

Comment: $\cos(y)$ makes it non linear

Comment: I would be thankful if you explain it .

Comment: A Linear differential Equation is a d.e. that is defined by a  linear polynomial in the unknown function and it’s derivatives (Wikipedia). Let’s make a simple example involving polynomials, which you should be familiar with: Is $x^3+2x^2 +e^x$ a linear polynomial?

Comment: Using `????` instead of `?` brings no content and only makes you look childish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the equation you're dealing with is $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x^2\cos y=0.$$

Because the highest-order derivative occurring in the equation is a second derivative, it's a second-order equation. The most general form of a second-order linear ordinary differential equation is $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+p(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+q(x)y=r(x),$$
where $p$, $q$, and $r$ can be any continuous functions of $x$. Notice that in that most general form, there are no functions of $y$ or of both $x$ and $y$, only of $x$. Therefore, the presence of $\cos y$ makes the entire equation non-linear.

Comment: Robert Howard it is second derivative sorry my bad i wrote it 2 times derivative.

Comment: Not a problem; is the equation in my answer more accurate now? And does the answer make sense?